# Why included recaptcha sdk to my android build in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, recaptcha

I don't use com.google.android.recaptcha:recaptcha sdk but when build to android in flutter, recaptcha sdk included, and my app rejected by google play store. what can i do???

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  easy_localization: ^3.0.1
  auto_size_text: ^3.0.0
  audioplayers: ^1.1.1
  hive: ^2.2.3
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
  dropdown_button2: ^2.0.0
  bip39: ^1.0.6
  bip32: ^2.0.0
  package_info_plus: ^3.0.2
  url_launcher: ^6.1.7
  permission_handler: ^10.2.0
  connectivity_plus: ^3.0.2
  usage_stats: ^1.2.0
  fluttertoast: ^8.1.2
  qr_flutter: ^4.0.0
  mobile_scanner: ^2.1.0
  lottie: ^2.2.0
  webview_flutter: ^4.0.1
  webview_flutter_android: ^3.1.3
  flutter_local_notifications: ^13.0.0
  flutter_secure_storage: ^8.0.0
  chopper: ^6.1.1
  json_annotation: ^4.8.0
  vibration: ^1.7.6
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.4
  flutter_riverpod: ^2.3.4
  flinq: ^2.0.2
  geolocator: ^9.0.2
  geocoding: ^2.1.0
  crypto: ^3.0.2
  encrypt: ^5.0.1
  shimmer: ^2.0.0
  device_info_plus: ^8.2.2
  uuid: ^3.0.7
  big_decimal: '<1.0.0'
  adbrixrm_flutter: ^2.1.0
  flutter_foreground_task: ^6.1.2
  sensors_plus: ^3.0.2
  share_plus: ^7.0.2
  firebase_core: ^2.15.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.16.0
  google_sign_in: ^6.1.4
  firebase_database: ^10.2.4
  firebase_messaging: ^14.6.5
  firebase_storage: ^11.5.3
  social_login_buttons: ^1.0.7
  marquee: ^2.2.3
  flutter_screenutil: ^5.7.0
  datetime_setting: ^2.0.2
  path_provider: ^2.1.1
  http: ^0.13.6
```

I want to know what plugin make recaptcha sdk, and remove recaptcha sdk from my app

Comment: I can find a solution from this link.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77798636/critical-security-vulnerability-in-recaptcha-enterprise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77798636/critical-security-vulnerability-in-recaptcha-enterprise)

Answer (score 1):

You can override reCaptcha version by adding [recaptcha_enterprise_flutter: ^18.4.0](https://pub.dev/packages/recaptcha_enterprise_flutter) or `implementation 'com.google.android.recaptcha:recaptcha:18.4.0'` in dependencies section of your app-level build.gradle file.

This happens because the last version firebase auth, uses recaptcha:18.1.2.

In [this github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/5638#issuecomment-1887702418) it is confirmed that the fix is scheduled for the next release.

Answer (score 0):

The Recaptcha SDK is used by Firebase Auth, so I believe it will be solved with the new update of Firebase Auth.

You can wait until then, try using lower versions, or Contact Firebase about the issue.