# Critical security vulnerability in reCAPTCHA Enterprise

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am building a Flutter app, and I am using Firebase Auth for authentication. I recently deployed my Flutter application via the play store, but got the following message:

> Your latest production release (106 (1.9.4)) contains SDK issues:
> com.google.android.recaptcha:recaptcha:18.1.2
> This SDK version has a note from the SDK developer. Here's what the SDK developer told us:
>
> A critical security vulnerability was discovered in reCAPTCHA Enterprise for Mobile. The vulnerability has been patched in the latest SDK release. Customers will need to update their Android application with the reCAPTCHA Enterprise for Mobile SDK, version 18.4.0 or above. We strongly recommend you update to the latest version as soon as possible.

**How can I fix this problem?** I am already using the latest version of flutter and firebase auth. My flutter doctor is coming back all healthy. My build.gradle files don't contain any references to reCAPTCHA. From what I can tell, the entire reCAPTCHA setup is handled by firebase?

Comment: The answer is right there in the message: _"Customers will need to update their Android application with the reCAPTCHA Enterprise for Mobile SDK, version 18.4.0 or above. We strongly recommend you update to the latest version as soon as possible."_ As shown earlier in that same message, you're currently using version 18.1.2. Upgrade to 18.4.0 or higher.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Yup. This makes sense, but I am still confused why firebase auth would not handle this? That service is used by millions of people every day. How can it be that I have to keep the package dependencies updated? It feels like there is something deeper wrong with my setup.

Comment: @MartinReindl What, you want someone else to change versions of packages on you without any predictability or control?  No thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update**: It has been fixed in the latest version of firebase_auth.

As answered by Martin Reindl, you can override reCaptcha version by adding [recaptcha_enterprise_flutter: ^18.4.0](https://pub.dev/packages/recaptcha_enterprise_flutter) or `implementation 'com.google.android.recaptcha:recaptcha:18.4.0'` in dependencies section of your app-level build.gradle file.

This happens because the last version firebase auth, uses recaptcha:18.1.2.

In [this github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/5638#issuecomment-1887702418) it is confirmed that the fix is scheduled for the next release.

Comment: i dont use recaptcha library.
do i need to install [recaptcha_enterprise_flutter: ^18.4.0](https://pub.dev/packages/recaptcha_enterprise_flutter) ?

is it that necessary ? @AbhinavSingh

or should i use just 
`implementation 'com.google.android.recaptcha:recaptcha:18.4.0' ` ?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by adding the package: [recaptcha_enterprise_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/recaptcha_enterprise_flutter). This forced the upgrade to 18.4.0.

I would still appreciate a more complete answer of why this is happening? It seems incredibly odd that I have to patch security issues in firebase auth manually (when the service is used by tens of millions of users every day).

Answer (score 0):

As the quickest and simplest solution I added implement com.google.android.recaptcha:recaptcha:18.4.0 to build.gradle  although I am not using recaptcha in my app. This method worked and the warning was gone